Scss with @use and @forward instead of @import in a multi UI themes scenario
I am trying to figure out how manage a migration from @import to @use/@forward directives in a multi theming scenario.
I have multiple set of variables directory and each one represents a UI theme.
With @import directive (soon removed https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/import/) the variables are in a global scope and if imported in the scss index file were recognized by all modules.
With @use or @foward the scope is limited to the file into which they are imported (!!!) so every scss component that use a variable must have at the beginning of the file the directive @use....
Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hrrgrh of what I mean and which should explain the problem: into ./src/scss/components/_*.scss need to add @use '../variables-[a|b]' that can not fit my needs to be "multi theming".
Any ideas how we can solve it?

I would suggest you move away from using SCSS variables and rather use CSS variables. Reason being SCSS variable values are resolved at compile time, not runtime. You have a lot more flexibility with CSS variables for this reason.
I'm not sure what the method is you're using to change themes, but say for instance your default is 'theme-a' and to switch to 'theme-b' a class 'theme-b' is added to the body element. In that case you could switch what variables are used like this:
:root {
  --accent-primary: #333;
  --accent-secondary: #fbfbfb;
}

.theme-b {
  --accent-primary: #fbfbfb;
  --accent-secondary: #333;
}

Hope that helps.

Thank you @josh-koter. But CSS vars are not suitable for SASS func (sass:color for example). You can not use
`

{
background-color: color.adjust(var(--primary), $lightness: 20%);
}
`


That is true, but you might not need a SASS func for that. You can use the natively supported CSS color-mix function. Eg:
background-color: color-mix(in hsl, var(--primary), white 20%);

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix
